# Creating a helloWorld plugin for Android using Cordova and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, cordova

I've done quite a bit of research and can't seem to find why this isn't working.  What I have is Cordova based Android app in Eclipse running Cordova 2.7.0.  I want to build a simple plugin that just alerts the user when it has completed.

My index.html

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.func = function(str,callback){
            alert("Outside Call Working");
            cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
        }
        function callPlugin(str){
            alert("JS Working");
            window.func(str,function(){
                alert("Done!");
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>PluginTest</h2>
    <a onclick="callPlugin('Plugin Working!')">Click me</a>
</body>
```

My config.xml line where I add the plugin

```
<plugin name="HelloPlugin" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.HelloPlugin" />
```

And my actual plugin HelloPlugin.java that is in src/com/example/plugintest right next to MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.plugintest;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class HelloPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        /*if(action.equals("echo")){
            String message = args.getString(0); 
            callbackContext.success(message);
            return true;
        }*/
        callbackContext.success(action);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of "HelloPlugin" in your config.xml should point to the package where the Java class is, so that Cordova can find and execute the Java code. So if you change 
`<plugin name="HelloPlugin" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.HelloPlugin" />`
to 
`<plugin name="HelloPlugin" value="com.example.plugintest.HelloPlugin" />`
I believe it should work.

Comment: Updated my config file and still no cigar.  If it helps the alerts I am getting are "JS Working" and then "Outside Call Working" and then I don't get anything, not even an error message.

Comment: When I do it, I get "JS Working", "Outside call working", "Done!", which is expected because you never get the return value ("Plugin Working" string in your callback.) 

I think since you are not getting anything the "Done" message, you still might have something messed up in your config. I had both of my files in `com.example.plugintest`, package, and the line in my config file was what I have above. You don't see _anything_ in the logs?

Comment: Thats what I've been doing.  I think it has something to do with cordova not being ready.  I'm playing with the deviceready listener but still not getting that to work.  Ill accept your answer as it's obviously working for you.  My config is the same as yours though.  So I dont know why it would work for you and not me.  Are you using cordova 2.7?

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't even realize that the code wasn't wrapped in an onDeviceReady() check. I guess Cordova is loading up before I have a chance to click the button. Yes, I am using 2.7. I am testing on a Nexus 7 device, maybe that is making a difference? Have you tried wrapping everything in onDeviceReady function, like this:
`document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){window.func = function(str,callback){
alert("Outside Call Working");
cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
        }
       }`

Comment: Yup. And I've even tried just putting an alert inside an ondeviceready like 'document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     function onDeviceReady(){
      alert("cordova");
  }'
And this doesn't even work.

Comment: And you don't get any logs, anywhere? Make sure "All Messages" is selected in the logcat view, sometimes I forget to do this and only see messages that are filtered. Did you make sure to set the target to Android 4.2? (Pretty sure you did because otherwise there would be build errors.) Where did you get the cordova.jar and cordova.js ? Phonegap.com? Have you been able to get _any_ cordova app to work that you could maybe compare the two projects?

Answer (score 4):

In this line

```
    window.func = function(str,callback){
        alert("Outside Call Working");
        cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
    }
```

put like this

```
window.func = function(str,callback){
        alert("Outside Call Working");
        cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"org.apache.cordova.plugin.HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
    }
```