# Hello world plugin for android using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build a hello world plugin for android using Cordova.The project runs without errors but i cant the result.My logcat returns the error `Error adding plugin`.Here is my code

javacript

```
window.func = function(str,callback){
            alert("Outside Call Working");
            cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
        }
        function callPlugin(str){
            alert("JS Working");
            window.func(str,function(){
                alert("Done!");
            });
        }
```

Android

```
public class HelloPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{

     @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            if(action.equals("echo")){
                String message = args.getString(0); 
                callbackContext.success(message);
                return true;
            }
            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        }     
}
```

config.xml

```
<feature name="HelloPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.ionicframework.myapp554544" />
    </feature>
```

**NOTE:**

The above codes stolen from ([Creating a helloWorld plugin for Android using Cordova and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657233/creating-a-helloworld-plugin-for-android-using-cordova-and-eclipse)) this question

**EDIT**

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>


    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


    <!-- plugin bridge js -->
    <script src="js/plugin.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body > 
      <a onclick="callPlugin('Plugin Working!')">Click me</a>   
  </body>
</html>
```

plugin.js

```
window.func = function(str,callback){
            alert("Outside Call Working");
            cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"org.apache.cordova.plugin.HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
        }
        function callPlugin(str){
            alert("JS Working");
            window.func(str,function(){
                alert("Done!");
            });
        }
```

HelloPlugin.java

```
package com.ionicframework.myapp554544;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class HelloPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{

     @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            if(action.equals("echo")){
                String message = args.getString(0); 
                callbackContext.success(message);
                return true;
            }
            callbackContext.success(action);
            return true;
        }     
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.myapp554544" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="Keyboard">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.ionic.keyboard.IonicKeyboard" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
<!--  Here is the plugin entry -->
    <plugin name="HelloPlugin" value="com.example.plugintest.HelloPlugin" />
<!-- end of plugin entry -->
    <name>myApp</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
```

should be changed to :

```
cordova.exec(callback, function(err){alert(err)},"org.apache.cordova.plugin.HelloPlugin","echo", [str]);
```

aslo change your xml entry to be:

```
<plugin name="HelloPlugin" value="com.example.plugintest.HelloPlugin" />
```

Comment: @Root this is another issue , but now your plugin is added.

Comment: I cant  understand which class is not found

Comment: Here is my logcat returns `call to unknown plugin org.apache.cordova.plugin.HelloPlugin"`

Comment: what is your xml entry ?

Comment: Again `class not found` :)

Comment: @Root can you submit full code , or even attach source files ?

Comment: @Root please add your code after applying my solution

Comment: @Root i cant see any <plugin> tag in your xml !!